# Tikzset node with centered custom text

Tags: tikz-node, tikzset

Alright I'm giving up. I want a custom node that looks like a common PI&D turbine or compressor symbol:

```
\tikzset{TC/.style={
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    path picture={
    \draw (-1,0.5) -- (1,1) -- ++ (0,-2) -- (-1,-0.5) -- cycle;
},
node contents={}
}
}
```

[image]

I would now like to add custom text in there, like "HP\ Turb". However, it always overlaps the borders and never gets aligned:

```
\tikzset{TC/.style={
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    text height=0.8cm,
    text width=1.8cm,
    align=center,
    path picture={
    \draw (-1,0.5) -- (1,1) -- ++ (0,-2) -- (-1,-0.5) -- cycle;
},
node contents={#1}
}
}
```

Almost everything is off:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: I would also love to have anchors at each corner and in the middle of each edge. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the built-in `trapezium` node shape (requires `shapes.geometric` library).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, trapezium, trapezium angle=70, trapezium stretches=true, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm, shape border rotate=90, align=center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] at (0,0){HP\\Turb};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Felix, you're welcome. As an aside, you should avoid calling other users 'sir' or using any gendered language on this site. No offense taken, just good general practice.

Comment: Thanks @Sandy G and big apologies! I will look to that from now.